# Укромкой [значение]

Tags: значение-слов

Укромкой - это как?
Ни на dic.academic, ни на викисловаре не нашёл толкования. Смысл ясен, но есть ли документальное его закрепление?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Документально" закрепил Платонов :

> А. П. Платонов. Город Градов (1926)
> Проезжие люди жили так, как будто они ехали по чужой планете, а не по отечественной стране; **каждый ел укромкой и соседу пищи не давал**, но все-таки люди жались друг к другу, ища защиты на страшных путях сообщения.
> (Нацкорпус)

Отрывок из книги "Жизнь языка : Памяти М.В.Панова" (сборник статей) :

> Среди наречий индивидуально-авторские образования у Платонова встречаются крайне редко. Безусловно окказиональными являются наречные сочетания в стоячку и в сидячку, образованные по типу слов внакидку: Что тебя носит по всей территории?! Ты бы лучше жила в сидячку и берегла силу и голову; Садись, старушка: в стоячку я не говорю («Ювенильное море»). Наречие укромкой по внешнему облику напоминает украдкой, оно совмещает в себе значения «укромно» и «украдкой»: …каждый ел укромкой и соседу пищи не давал.

В современном творческо-сетевом дискурсе (стихи, проза, форумные разговоры) наречие *укромкой* достаточно распространено.

Answer (score 4):

Даль утверждает, что наречие укромкой - от глагола укромить:
http://www.vidahl.holm.ru/P235.HTM#40804

УКРОМЛЯТЬ, укромить что, от(раз,за)городить, отделить перегородкой окроме, особо, по себе. Укромить закром, разгородить надвое, для разных хлебов. -ся, страдат. | Отделиться от людей, от света в одиночество, уединиться. Укромное местечко, укрома ж. укром м. свое, особое, отдельное; малое и скромное, тихое; приют, притон, пристанище, одинокая отрада, уютное уединенье. Волк в лес овцу тащил, в укромный уголок, Крылов. Укромные местечки для насадок, Крылов. Живут они укромно, тихо, скромно, тесно, но уютно. Так приезжай же в мой укром, в мою укрому! в приют. Укромность, свойство, качество по прилаг., уют, комфорт. Укромшить кого, кур. обделить, обидеть, обрезать кругом; - что, укроить, окоротить, обузить в кройке, укромсать. | Укромшить кого, тамб. сокротить (кроткий), уходить, убить. Укромкий, -мистый пск. твер. кто держится окроме от людей, бол. своенравный, либо скупой, кто кромит себе.

Comment: В толковых академических словарях его и искать не стоило, это же разговорное слово

Comment: Даль не приводит в своем Словаре наречие "укромкой". Я лично не нашел. И Даль ничего не "утверждает". Происхождение слова понятно и так.

Answer (score 0):

> Даль утверждает, что наречие укромкой - от глагола укромить

По сути - да, но формально-то скорее напрямую от ***кром, укромный*** - однокоренное с "закрома" - с общим значением морфа "прятать", "урывать", "утаивать".